# I want to append to echo statement in one line in UNIX

Tags: unix

```
read Name?" Enter Full name "

First= echo $Name | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

I am using this command to cut Full name, but it automatically print first name. which  I don't want.

I want an output like
James, This is prime number.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell I use (bash on MacOS), this following works.

```
read -p "Enter full name " first last

echo Hi $first, you are the man
```

Please specify what shell you are using.

Another thing to note, is that in order to assign to the variable 'First' in your question, in bash you need to do surround the command with backticks `` or the $() construction, as follows.

```
First=$(echo $Name | cut -d ' ' -f1)
```